# Playwright Java url() method returns URL of previous page

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I my test I navigiate from PageA to PageB throught locator click,
After click I try to get url via page.url(), which returned url of PageA.

For now solution I could achieve was page.reload().url(), which really returned right URL.
(no any wait can help here, the page object just does not fetch latest url)

What can i do in this situation to avoid reload?

Answer (score 0):

Use [waitForURL](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url).

As it waits for the main frame to navigate to the given URL.

```
page.click("a.delayed-navigation"); // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
page.waitForURL("**/target.html");
```